# Inserting rows to xls document using Apache Poi (using shiftrows())

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to insert some rows in an xls document, using Apache Poi. I am using shiftrows() to achieve this. 
The document contains some hidden rows. (zero height)
Although rows are shifted in a way that I have new rows in the position I want, I face a strange issue. 
The rows below the inserted rows are mixed up. If I remove the hidden rows from the document, apart from a small issue everything seems to work fine with shifting. 
Inserting rows in Excel also works without any problem. 
Thanks in advance for any hint/help.

Comment: Could you tell how exactly they are mixed up? Are they not hidden anymore? Something else?

Comment: Yes some of them are not hidden anymore. Depends on the number of rows I add. Also some not hidden rows loose merge in cells or even disappear (again depends on the number of rows I add). If I remove the hidden rows or expand them so they are not zero height except a small issue, it works quite good.

Comment: Could you include some code snippet of you currently have? Also, seems like you are not actually hiding the rows but just making them zero height. Using the hide feature might give you more predictable behavior.

Comment: Ι have not created this document myself. It comes from a client. If I use select all in Excel---> Format ---> Visibility ---> Unhide rows, they show up... If I resize their height manually row by row, obviously they show up again. So I don't really know if they are just zero height or "properly" hidden. I just do this  sheet.shiftRows(startPosition,  sheet.getLastRowNum()+1, numOfRows, true, true);

Comment: Help us help you. Edit your question with a code snippet exhibiting the issue. How are the rows mixed up? are the hidden rows above or below the shifted rows?